# While using lattice, graph doen't appear at ONLY 1st panel

Tags: r, panel, lattice

While I doing Course project 1 in Reproducible Research, Week2, Coursera, the problem occurs.

[Here is the github link.](https://github.com/Baescott/RepData_PeerAssessment1/blob/master/PA1_template.Rmd)

In this project, the problem occurs in below part.

```
newact_ind <- cbind(newactivity, a)
colnames(newact_ind)[ncol(newact_ind)] <- "Indicator"

new_meanstep <- tapply(newact_ind$steps, newact_ind$interval, mean)

interval <- as.integer(levels(newact_ind$interval))

library(lattice)
xyplot(new_meanstep ~ interval | Indicator, data=newact_ind, layout=c(1,2), 
       type="l", xlab="Interval", ylab="Number of steps")
```

This plot should show time series plot split by Indicator (weekday & weekend), but result likes below.

[image]

Why does this happening?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example. This will give people that want to help you something to work with and to test. 
You can read about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: Ah, thanks for comment. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: @KoenV I edited.

Comment: The link is not working. Please have a look.

Comment: @KoenV I edited again. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Please provide a small part of the data you are using: *newact_ind* or *newactivity* and *a*. You cannot expect people to go through all the lines of code you wrote in your assignment.

Comment: @KoenV  Thanks for advices. I'll write another question with more details. :)

Comment: Good luck on your next question. Give me a sign when you posted it and I will have a look.